# Как сделать контрастность изображения

Tags: java, android

Начал разбираться с примером кадрирования изображений:

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

Получается, мы кадрируем изображение через приложение галерея. Так вот, как сделать, чтобы можно было манипулировать контрастностью изображения или какие-либо другие изменения над изображением через приложение галерея?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Стандартное приложение "галерея" этого не умеет. Более того, даже приведенный код будет работать далеко не на всех телефонах. Потому, что не у всех телефонов есть приложение, которое умеет обрезать изображения. Это недукументированный функционал, использовать который не рекомендуется в силу того, что он совершенно не обязательно входит в прошивки разных производителей.